# R dynamic data frame names in Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic

I have some df like

df1 
df2
df3
...
dfn

So how to use my data frame using loop

example:

loop (i in 1:n)
{
summary (paste0 ("df",i))     **#       =====> It dose not work!**

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the value of the string objects in a `list`, then loop through the `list` with `lapply` get the `summary`

```
lapply(mget(paste0("df", seq_len(n))), summary)
```

---

If we are using a `for` loop, make sure that we store the results in an object, preferably a `list`, use `get` to return the value of the object, get the `summary` and store it as `list` element in the 'out' object

```
out <- vector('list', n)
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
   out[[i]] <- summary(get(paste0("df", i)))
 }
```

---

NOTE: It is better to have all the `data.frame` in a `list`.  But, in case we want to update the original objects in the global environment using `for` loop use `assign`

```
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
  assign(paste0("df", i), get(paste0("df", i))[-(1:3)])
 }
```

Or this can be done with `list2env` after using `lapply`

```
list2env(lapply(mget(paste0("df", seq_len(n))), function(x) x[-(1:3)]), .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6, col3 = 7:9, col4 = 10:12)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:15, col2 = 16:30, col3 = 31:45, col4 = 46:60)
n <- 2
```

Comment: **Great Job!** <br/> I think get is the answer!

Comment: but how tranfer this code   _df1 <- df1[, c(-1,-2,-3)]_ to dynamic like _get(paste0("df", i)) <- get(paste0("df", i))[, c(-1,-2,-3)]_

Comment: @TuongNguyen  If you need to subset the dataset in a loop, `lapply(mget(paste0('df', seq_len(n))), function(x) x[-(1:3)])` or with `for` loop `for(i in seq_len(n)) { out[[i]] <- get(paste0("df", i))[-(1:3)] }`

Comment: what is out[[i]] ? all I need is df1 :)

Comment: @TuongNguyen  I think you need a `list` of data.frame as output.  If you only need `df1` just do `df1[-(1:3)]` why go for `get` and stuff?

Comment: It must auto run from 1 to 9 :( do you understand my ideal. I do not have any output data frame. I should be the old,  ( df1 <df1[....]

Comment: @TuongNguyen  That is the reason I showed with `list`.  I am not sure what you are trying to say.  If you want the original objects to be updated it can be done, but it is better to have all data.frame in a `list`

Comment: Extractly I would like to change df.n to df.n[,c(-(1:3))]

Comment: @TuongNguyen  Updated the post

Comment: paste0 ("df_",i ) <- get ((paste0 ("df_",i )))[ , c(-2,-3,-48,-42,-43,-44,-45)]     => Error in paste0("df_", i) <- get((paste0("df_",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: @TuongNguyen  I showed a reproducible example and it is working fine

Comment: Could you please help me solve this issue, after use your code to change data frame, now I would like to change colname:   #assign (colnames(get(paste0("df_",i))[y]) , paste0 (colnames(get(paste0("df_",i))[y]), i))
    temp_colname <- paste0 (colnames(get(paste0("df_",i))[y]), i)
    colnames(get(paste0("df_",i))[y]) <-  temp_colname  => both way is wrong